# Cannot build bitcoin

Tags: fedora, bitcoin

Get sauce from [github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git), read instructions in doc/build-unix.txt. But `make` can not into compile!

[urs1412@noname bitcoin]$ `cd src`

[urs1412@noname src]$ `make -f makefile.unix`

```unix
g++ -c -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security \
-Wno-unused-parameter -g -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE \
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/home/urs1412/w/bitcoin/src \
-I/home/urs1412/w/bitcoin/src/obj -DUSE_UPNP=0 -DUSE_IPV6=1 \
-I/home/urs1412/w/bitcoin/src/leveldb/include \
-I/home/urs1412/w/bitcoin/src/leveldb/helpers \
-DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -fno-stack-protector \
-fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector \
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -MMD -MF obj/alert.d \
-o obj/alert.o alert.cpp \

alert.cpp:6:53: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp: 
No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/alert.o] Error 1
```

td;dr could not build [bitcoin](/questions/tagged/bitcoin), dumping system info

[urs1412@noname src]$ uname -r

3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64

[urs1412@noname src]$ git log -n 1

commit 77a1e12eed5fc66dce16584696f54988a8c2bf4e
Merge: fe15aa3 0565b71
Author: Gavin Andresen 
Date:   Wed Apr 24 08:48:06 2013 -0700

```
Merge pull request #2554 from fanquake/qt-pro-brew-patch

bitcoin-qt.pro Brew patch
```

Comment: Fedora 18 by the way, now installed boost and boost-devel. now getting a different error message. removed fedoras default openssl package; next try build openssl from saource

Comment: There was some progress. Easy depencencies: boost, boost-devel. Hard mode: Also needs an openssl buid  WITH EC EXTENSION which is not available in fedora because of copyright issues.

Comment: cd bitcoin && make -f makefile.unix #after install openssl

Comment: In file included from serialize.h:22:0, from netbase.h:10, from util.h:29, from alert.h:13, from alert.cpp:11:

Comment: allocators.h:12:53: fatal error: openssl/crypto.h: No such file or directory

Comment: crypto.h is in /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/crypto.h

Comment: Where is g++ looking for it, or how to tell g++ where to look for it?

Comment: even if you fix that problem, ec.h is missing from RH distros: http://www.mentby.com/Group/freeradius-users/centos-6-compile-error.html

Comment: you can tell where g++ is looking for it using strace. send the strace output to a file using -o/path/filename so you can wade through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally was able to build bitcoin-1.8 (*not* the git sources, although I believe these same steps will be applicable) on my CentOS VPS.

Here are the packages I had to install. Note that I had to build some of these.

As root:

```
yum install gcc-c++ make
install boost-devel 
yum install db4-devel
yum install openssl-devel  # but this didn't provide ec.h, hence the next steps
yum install rpm-build
rpm -U ~jcomeau/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/openssl-devel-1.0.0e-1.x86_64.rpm 
yum install lynx  # for downloading some source packages
yum install python-devel  # for building miniupnpc
rpm -i ~jcomeau/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/libminiupnpc9-1.8.20130503-0.1.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -i ~jcomeau/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/libminiupnpc-devel-1.8.20130503-0.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Then as user, `make BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mt all test`

If you need instructions on building the openssl-devel (the spec file was in the sources and mostly functional) and libminiupnpc-devel (I got the spec file from an OpenSUSE source RPM and adapted it) let me know.

I believe your immediate problem is you didn't install openssl-devel. But you will likely run into these other problems after that, if you don't do some of the steps I did.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that boost library for gcc is working correctly. Try a test "hello world" program with boost. You can find it in the directory: BOOST_BUILD_PATH/example/hello
Compile it with BOOST_BUILD_PATH/bin/b2 toolset=gcc
If it doesnt work then boost is not correctly installed.